# Asp.net Memebership Authorization without password

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, facebook

To authanticate users in Asp.net Membership we can call method

```
FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(username, password)
```

how can I do the same job (generate session, cookies and all other staff that Authanticate does) without users password?

I'm trying to login user over facebook connect. User's facebook id is stored within the users data. User should be signed in like a normal user.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you can use the SetAuthCookie method.

more info here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.setauthcookie.aspx

Comment: ASP.NET MVC 4 Simple Membership WebSecurity Source - see "Login" method: http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/854bcdb520dc#src/WebMatrix.WebData/WebSecurity.cs

Comment: that does not work
when i ask WebSecurity.CurrentUserName it gives me the previous user.!!

Comment: @AmirMagdy do you find a better solution? Does it still cause the same problem?

Comment: @Sam yep just do a redirect right after so the cookie is refreshed for the page and it'll work