# Facebook authentication and Asp.Net Membership

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

I'm trying to integrate facebook authentication with an asp.net site.

So if a user decides to register at the site they can do so by using their facebook credentials.

I'm currently at the point where I have the facebook access token and the user details and not sure how I should go from here.

The site uses asp.net membership authorization.

This is what I believe should happen in case a new user decides to register: (But not sure if this the the way to go)

0) User visits the site and decides to register using their facebook credentials.
1) The user providers their credentials and I receive an access token and their user information.
2) I store this information in my database and create an asp.net membership user with the data I received. **(At this point I'd have to generate a password).**
3) Log the user into the site so he can navigate freely.

I would appreciate some advice if I'm on the correct path and how I should go about generating the password. (I'm thinking in maybe combining the email and facebook userId, retrieve a hash and store.)

Thanks

**UPDATE 1**
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871010/asp-net-memebership-authorization-without-password) SO question where they suggest to use:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.setauthcookie(v=VS.90).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you approach is sound; what you effectively do is to replace the username/password authentication with the received facebook id, and let that id pass as a valid identifier in you application.

You say that you will need to generate a password in you application which I am note entirely sure about. It is true that you will need to create your user with a password as far as the membership provider in ASP.NET is concerned, but you could choose to fill in a random string if you only want the users to login using facebook connections.

Deciding which facebook attribute to bind to is also worth a bit of concideration. The natural choice is of course the facebook identifier since that is unqiue to the user, but if you choose to allow other authentication mechanisms later on - google open id for one - you might also benefit from storing the email from facebook etc.

Probably it will also be a good idea to auto generate a user name in you application that is not defined by facebook. If you choose the facebook identifier as login name you have a hard dependency on facebook making the introduction of new identity providers hard. If you choose a random identifier and an associative table establishing the connection between the facebook id and your id, you will also gain some flexibility later on. Choosing the somewhat more limiting email address might be a better choice if you want to have meaningful output from ASP.NET Login-controls like LoginStatus etc.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't read the response below/above so this may have been covered but be warned that I ran into a serious problem with cookies not being set from within an iframe in IE. It was a bloody nightmare. I'm not sure if this has been fixed, if its fixable, but just be conscious of my experience and test thoroughly in *all* browsers.

Also checkout the [.net open auth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/) project. I haven't used it personally but it supposedly supports OAuth as well as OpenId & ICards, which could be helpful later on for additional integration points.