# MVC4 WebSecurity SimpleMembership Login without password

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication

I want to create a simple feature that allows the Admin to login in as any other user

WebSecurity.Login won't work because i keep only hashes of passwords so i don't have those,

i tried using FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie but that just doesn't do anything, WebSecurity.CurrentUserName returned value Does Not Change.

I also tried WebSecurity.Logout ad FormsAuthentication.Logout before using SetAuthCookie but that didn't work either.

Comment: What didn't work about `FormAuthenication.SetAuthCookie()`?  If you use this method, you have to do a redirect for the new cookie to work.

Comment: Redirect to a specific URL or just redirect, let me try that

Comment: I Still get the previously logged in user principal! after redirection
so WebSecurity.CurrentUserName Returns the previous userName

Comment: i used good old fashioned asp.net 
`context.Response.Redirect("/");` and it worked thank you

Comment: It's should, it is [an answer on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14197528/how-do-i-manually-log-a-user-in-using-websecurity-simplemembership).